# Job application: What are "scientific highlights"?

Tags: application, faculty-application, application-cover-letter

A job opening for a tenure track position specifies that the application must include "scientific highlights".

Now I am puzzled by this. I've applied before for tenure-track positions, and I've never heard of such a thing.
I don't get the difference with other more standard ingredients of an application, such as research statement, list of publications, cv, cover letter; this is even more puzzling because these latter standard ingredients are also specifically required in this job advert.

Any clue?

Comment: Have you asked the contact person responsible for advertising this post?

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: This is in Norway. I thought about asking the responsible person, but, sadly, there is no time due to the deadline being too soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is self-descriptive.  It is (often but now always) a short statement that can be used to easily remember your file.

This type of request is also a regular interview question disguised as “what should I remember you for”?

For context consider that there are often multiple 10s if not 100s of applicants for a position, and search committee will not have time to read all your papers and those of all the other applicants.  So this is your chance to select your 2 or 3 best contributions and increase the odd at least one person in the committee pay particular attention to the stuff you highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some interpretations:

What are your top academic achievements?

If we ask a random person in your community, what will they know you for?

What are your selected publications (ones you’re most proud of)?

Did you win any awards or fellowships? What for?

The department wants to hire people whose work is outstanding in some way- they want to know how you are outstanding.